# Insert Into EXEC xp_dirtree with derived column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to use the xp_dirtree stored procedure to create a complete file path in a SSRS report using :

```
CREATE TABLE #tt1 (
       id int IDENTITY(1,1)
      ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
      ,depth int
      ,isfile bit);

INSERT #tt1 
EXEC xp_dirtree @dir, 10, 1
```

however as an addition i would like to add a column into the insert on-top of the stored procedure. so something like

```
CREATE TABLE #tt1 (
       id int IDENTITY(1,1)
      ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
      ,depth int
      ,isfile bit
      ,NewColumn nvarchar(100)
      );

INSERT #tt1 
EXEC xp_dirtree @dir, 10, 1, 'NEW COLUMN'
```

However this doesn't work and kicks out

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Procedure xp_dirtree, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Comment: Short answer - you can't this directly. That is a limitation of how a stored procedure works - the resultset is defined within the procedure. There are work-arounds for the situation you post. However, tsql really isn't the correct tool to interrogate the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the column while using `insert into . .` statement :

```
INSERT INTO #tt1 (subdirectory, depth, isfile, NewColumn)
     EXEC xp_dirtree @dir, 10, 1, 'NEW COLUMN'
```

Comment: @XDSA5286. . . That because of `SP` returns less or more column that the column list specified in `INSERT INTO` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a 3 level structure to draw a report and compare data, I have worked past this issue by first inserting into a temp table and thereafter inserting into the primary table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('PC_TABLE'))BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE PC_TABLE ([PARENT_PK] INT,
    [NAME] NVARCHAR(255),
    [DEPTH] INT,
    [FILE] INT,
    [P_PK] INT DEFAULT NULL)
END;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('PC_TABLE1'))BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE PC_TABLE1 ([PARENT_PK] INT,
    [NAME] NVARCHAR(255),
    [DEPTH] INT,
    [FILE] INT,
    [P_PK] INT DEFAULT NULL)
END;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('PC_TABLE2'))BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE PC_TABLE2 ([PARENT_PK] INT,
    [NAME] NVARCHAR(255),
    [DEPTH] INT,
    [FILE] INT,
    [P_PK] INT DEFAULT NULL)
END;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TEMP_PC_TABLE'))BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE TEMP_PC_TABLE ([PARENT_PK] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [NAME] NVARCHAR(255),
    [DEPTH] INT,
    [FILE] INT, )
END;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TEMP_PC_TABLE1'))BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE TEMP_PC_TABLE1 ([PARENT_PK] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [NAME] NVARCHAR(255),
    [DEPTH] INT,
    [FILE] INT, )
END;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TEMP_PC_TABLE2'))BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE TEMP_PC_TABLE2 ([PARENT_PK] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [NAME] NVARCHAR(255),
    [DEPTH] INT,
    [FILE] INT, )
END
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FOLDERPATH NVARCHAR(MAX) ='C:\YourFolderPathHere\'
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL=N'EXEC xp_DirTree '''+@FOLDERPATH+''', 1, 1'
    PRINT @SQL
    INSERT INTO TEMP_PC_TABLE EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
    INSERT INTO PC_TABLE(PARENT_PK, NAME, DEPTH, [FILE], P_PK)
    SELECT PARENT_PK, NAME, DEPTH, [FILE], NULL
    FROM TEMP_PC_TABLE TPT
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PC_TABLE PT WHERE TPT.NAME=PT.NAME AND TPT.DEPTH=PT.DEPTH)
    DECLARE @FOLDER VARCHAR(MAX), @PK INT
    DECLARE F_PATH CURSOR FOR
    SELECT NAME AS 'FOLDER', PARENT_PK AS 'PK'
    FROM PC_TABLE
    WHERE [FILE]=0 AND NAME NOT LIKE '%\%'
    OPEN F_PATH
    FETCH NEXT FROM F_PATH
    INTO @FOLDER, @PK
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
        PRINT @FOLDERPATH
        SET @SQL=N'EXEC xp_DirTree '''+@FOLDERPATH+@FOLDER+'\'+''', 1, 1'
        PRINT 'SQL GOES HERE \|/'
        PRINT @SQL
        INSERT INTO TEMP_PC_TABLE1 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
        INSERT INTO PC_TABLE1(PARENT_PK, NAME, DEPTH, [FILE], P_PK)
        SELECT PARENT_PK, NAME, DEPTH, [FILE], @PK
        FROM TEMP_PC_TABLE1 TPT
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PC_TABLE1 P1 WHERE P1.NAME=TPT.NAME AND P1.P_PK=@PK)
        TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_PC_TABLE1
        DECLARE @FPATH1 VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @PPK INT, @FNAME VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE FPATH1 CURSOR FOR SELECT NAME, P_PK FROM PC_TABLE1 WHERE [FILE]=0
        OPEN FPATH1
        FETCH NEXT FROM FPATH1
        INTO @FNAME, @PPK
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
            PRINT @FOLDERPATH
            SET @SQL=N'EXEC xp_DirTree '''+@FOLDERPATH+@FNAME+'\'+''', 1, 1'
            PRINT 'SQL GOES HERE \|/'
            PRINT @SQL
            INSERT INTO TEMP_PC_TABLE2 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
            INSERT INTO PC_TABLE2(PARENT_PK, NAME, DEPTH, [FILE], P_PK)
            SELECT PARENT_PK, NAME, DEPTH, [FILE], @PK
            FROM TEMP_PC_TABLE2 TPT
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PC_TABLE2 P1 WHERE P1.NAME=TPT.NAME AND P1.P_PK=@PPK)
            TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_PC_TABLE2
            FETCH NEXT FROM FPATH1
            INTO @FNAME, @PPK
        END
        CLOSE FPATH1
        DEALLOCATE FPATH1
        FETCH NEXT FROM F_PATH
        INTO @FOLDER, @PK
    END
    CLOSE F_PATH
    DEALLOCATE F_PATH
END
```